# Is there a way to create or open an Excel workbook from AppleScript without it becoming the foreground window?

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I'm trying to create an AppleScript that can create and/or open existing workbook but not make it the foreground window. If the user is already working on a workbook I don't want to interrupt them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that

```
tell application "Appname"
launch -- versus activate
--
end tell
```

Will start the app and work every screen in the background.